# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable when trying to get the user input

Tags: python

i get this kind of error when i run my code but i didnt understood what does it mean i try to google for similar case but i didnt find anything .this is the error i get when i pressed the no responde

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                             
  File "/home/main.py", line 27, in <module>                                                                                                   
    dataCheck(data);                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/main.py", line 24, in dataCheck                                                                                                  
    values=data();                                                                                                                             
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

and here is the code i wrote :

```
print("Welcome to the game!");


def data():
    name=input("Give me your name: ");
    lname=input("Give me your last name: ");
    age=int(input("Give me your age: "));
    return (name,lname,age);

def dataCheck(data):
    name=data[0];
    lname=data[1];
    age=str(data[2]);
    print("Your name: "+name);
    print("Your Last name: "+lname);
    print("Your age: "+age);
    yn=input("The information are true Y/N :");
    if yn.lower()=="y":
        print("Welcome "+name);
    elif yn.lower()=="n":
        values=data();
        dataCheck(values);
data=data();
dataCheck(data);
```

Comment: your parameter name in `dataCheck` and function name is same.

Comment: it is the good now everything working fine thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have a namespace collision. Once you say `data = data()`, the function `data()` is gone, so when you call it with `values = data()`, you're trying to call the value it returned before.

Try this.

```
print("Welcome to the game!")

def get_data():
    name = input("Give me your name: ")
    lname = input("Give me your last name: ")
    age = int(input("Give me your age: "))
    return (name, lname, age)

def data_check(data):
    name, lname, age = data
    print("Your name: " + name)
    print("Your Last name: " + lname)
    print("Your age: " + str(age))
    yn = input("The information are true Y/N :")
    if yn.lower() == "y":
        print("Welcome " + name)
    elif yn.lower() == "n":
        data_check(get_data())

data_check(get_data())
```

Note I also

- Removed the semicolons (you don't need those in Python)
- `snake_cased` the `data_check` function (that's the convention)
- Used tuple unpacking instead of individual assignment in `data_check()`, it's handy shortcut

Answer (score 1):

At one level, you made a mistake because you defined `data` as a function, redefined `data` as what the function returned and eventually tried to use `data` as the function that you defined at first (and Python complained that you are trying to use a tuple as a function: `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`). Using different names for the function and the player info will suffice to solve your issue.

At another level, you *named* your function wrong.  Functions represent *actions*, hence you should try to use action names for them.  `dataCheck` is OK, (that, or `check_data` if you want to stress the verb), `data` is no good, `get_data` could be OK but `get_player_data` is even better, coupled with `check_player_data` as well.

---

As a first footnote, instead of `name=data[0];` etc it's more idiomatic to unpack the whole tuple/list as in `a, b, c = data`.

---

Second one, Your `dataCheck` is not producing a result... were `data` in need of an edit you get new `values` but `data` is not going to be modified by your function.

---

Third and last, if you want to edit `data` in `checkData`, don't do

```
    elif yn == 'n':
        data = get_data()
```

because that's going to create a local assignment that is not reverberated at the level of the caller's name space.

Answer (score 1):

always use some unique variable name or pay attention on function/variable name. In your case due to same name, it is considering data as tuple not the one you are trying to refer to.
please compare difference from your code and below.

```
print("Welcome to the game!");


def Input_data():
    name=input("Give me your name: ");
    lname=input("Give me your last name: ");
    age=int(input("Give me your age: "));
    return (name,lname,age);

def dataCheck(data):
    name=data[0];
    lname=data[1];
    age=str(data[2]);
    print("Your name: "+name);
    print("Your Last name: "+lname);
    print("Your age: "+age);
    yn=input("The information are true Y/N :");
    if yn.lower()=="y":
        print("Welcome "+name);
    elif yn.lower()=="n":
        values=Input_data();
        dataCheck(values);
data=Input_data();
dataCheck(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
def data_fn():
    name=input("Give me your name: ");
    lname=input("Give me your last name: ");
    age=int(input("Give me your age: "));
    return (name,lname,age);

def dataCheck(data):
    name=data[0];
    lname=data[1];
    age=str(data[2]);
    print("Your name: "+name);
    print("Your Last name: "+lname);
    print("Your age: "+age);
    yn=input("The information are true Y/N :");
    if yn.lower()=="y":
        print("Welcome "+name);
    elif yn.lower()=="n":
        values=data_fn();   # instead of calling the tuple as function call the function itself
        dataCheck(values);
data=data_fn();
dataCheck(data);
```

The issue with your code was that you were calling `tuple` as a function hence the error: **`'tuple' object is not callable`**.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `raw_input`, the `raw_input` will return `<type 'str'>`, and with `input`, if you want to input a string, you should use like this:

```

> a = input('a:')
>   a: 'your input string'
>   ```